# OneSignal REST API to send push notification, but I get a 500 error

Tags: onesignal

I have a Perl script I've written, and I'm trying to send a test push notification out using **OneSignal**. Here is my *JSON* (prettified, for readability);

```
 {
    "contents": {
        "en": "Here are your daily picks!"
    },
    "app_id": "id_here",
    "app_ids": ["id_here"],
    "include_player_ids": ["aabaa581-b54a-4348-81cb-00ed65c1adf8"]
 }
```

I get an error message, in plain HTML:

```
  <p id="message" class="text">An Unexpected Error Occurred</p>
  <p id="submessage" class="text">Error Code: 500</p>
  <p id="explanation" class="text">
    We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us.
  </p>
```

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I've got it! I'll put the answer here, in case others have the same issue in the future. Basically, you **don't** need to provide both the 1app_id`AND`app_ids` params. The documentation is a bit mis-leading:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

[image]

If you just use the `app_id`, then it sends out fine :)